# How to find source_location of the code executed by super?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, super

```
class C1
  def pr
    puts 'C1'
  end
end

class C2 < C1
  def pr
    puts 'C2'
    super
    puts self.method(:pr).source_location
  end
end

c = C2.new
c.pr
```

In the program above is it possible to obtain location of the code executed by `super` (`C1::pr` in our case) as well as we obtain the location of `C2::pr` code using `source_location` method?

Comment: Knowing that the method is going to re-despatch via `super` from the outside is *hard*, but finding ancestor classes that implement `pr` and getting those source locations is reasonably straightforward.

Comment: `method(:your_method).super_method.source_location`

Answer (score 33):

From ruby 2.2 you can use `super_method` like this:

```
Class A
  def pr
    puts "pr"
  end
end

Class B < A
  def pr
    puts "Super method: #{method(:pr).super_method}"
  end
end
```

As `super_method` returns a Method, you can chain them to find the ancestor:

```
def ancestor(m)
  m = method(m) if m.is_a? Symbol
  super_m = m.super_method
  if super_m.nil?
    return m
  else
    return ancestor super_m
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

You just have to get to the superclass, then use `instance_method` to get the method from the superclass.

```
class C2 < C1
  def pr
    puts "C2"
    super
    puts "Child: #{self.method(:pr).source_location}"
    puts "Parent: #{self.class.superclass.instance_method(:pr).source_location}"
  end
end
```

**EDIT**—regarding the comment about checking the ancestry chain, it (surprisingly) seems to be unnecessary.

```
class C1
  def pr
    puts "C1"
  end
end

class C2 < C1; end

class C3 < C2
  def pr
    puts "C3"
    super
    puts "Child source location: #{self.method(:pr).source_location}"
    puts "Parent source location: #{self.class.superclass.instance_method(:pr).source_location}"
  end
end

c = C3.new
c.pr
```

prints

```
C3
C1
Child source location: ["source_location.rb", 10]
Parent source location: ["source_location.rb", 2]
```

Comment: I think this answer could be extended to look at ancestors list and check whether any of them implement `pr` - was looking at same, and is best I can come up with

Comment: Remember: `super` also calls methods defined in included modules, so checking only methods defined in super classes may not cover all super methods.

Answer (score 6):

As per @bukk530, `super_method` gets you what you want but a good way to access it via the console is

```
ClassName.new.method(:method_name).super_method.source_location
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) you could use the `-s` flag to show the super method. Documentation about the feature is [here](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Source-browsing#super-flag).

```
show-source Class#method -s
```

Answer (score 2):

### To See the Whole Ancestry Of The Method...

Define this in an `irb` session:

```
class Object
  def method_ancestry(method_name)
    method_ancestors = []
    method = method(method_name)
    while method
      method_ancestors << [method.owner, method.source_location]
      method = method.super_method
    end
    method_ancestors
  end
end
```

For instance, in the Rails console, I can do:

```
# assuming User is an ActiveRecord class
User.new.method_ancestry(:save)

=> [[ActiveRecord::Suppressor,
  ["/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb", 40]],
 [ActiveRecord::Transactions,
  ["/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb", 317]],
 [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty,
  ["/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb",
   21]],
 [ActiveRecord::Validations,
  ["/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb", 43]],
 [ActiveRecord::Persistence,
  ["/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb", 124]]]
```

This list alone doesn't tell you whether any of the method definitions listed actually call `super` or just override their inherited definition. But if you see `super` in one of them, it goes to the next one in the list.

If you use this a lot, you might put it in your `~/.irbrc` or `~/.pryrc`.